# Problems loading jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when I publish with IIS 7. I get the following errors:

> The style sheet (CSS) http: // localhost: 8001 / Content / css /? V =
>   uz6OViW7dDMwKlkmrPG7KyAFoSRbh3Vh9J_67n9lwGQ1 was not loaded because
>   its MIME type, "text / html", is not "text / css".
>
> There was a failure to load the source "https:
>   //www.***.com.mx/aguilaportal/Scripts/js". aguilaportal: 454
>
> A synchronous XMLHttpRequest in the main thread is disapproved for its
>   negative effects on the end user experience. For more help check http:
>   //xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, has '<' [Learn more]

Investigating the network, there is no error of any sale, but when published and when I am on the server  the errors appear.

Does anyone know why?

I am using these types and styles.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https: /maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href = '// fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Robot:400,300' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text / css' />
<link href = '// fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic.700italic' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text / css' />
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "// maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script type = "text / javascript" src = "~ / Scripts / js / jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</ script>

@ Styles.Render ("~ / Content / css")
```

Comment: May be cos you got spaces on your different URL's, a little bit trim can solve your problem.

Comment: Formatting improved. Some spelling improved.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of spaces and line breaks. And spaces. I removed those and fixed your font name which was miss-spelled I think. From Robot to Roboto. Also, just for testing I included a different jQuery because I have no way to test if you local location of jQuery is in the correct spot or not. Copy my code and paste it. Then debug location of your jQuery.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic.700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
-->
@ Styles.Render ("~ / Content / css")
```

Comment: I already tried your code but still I did not correct the error

Comment: Sorry, then it must be something else in your code that you have not linked. It works like I have posted above in a clean environment.